# How to write a unit test case for Login Activity in android

Tags: android, junit4

I have written a login activity. When login buttons clicks, i am doing authentication in below code.

```
  loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
            // Get username and password
            // check username or password with db or webservice
            }
            }
```

Please help me how to write a unit test case for authentication success or not?

Comment: Hi nag, did you done it, actually i need to write same kind unit test cases.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**
**TestMe**(https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9471-testme)

Auto Generate Unit Tests for source class in Java or Groovy.
No more boilerplate!

**Features:**

- Auto-generate Java or Groovy test code with JUnit 4/5, TestNG or Spock frameworks
- Auto-generate Mockito mocks
- Generate test params and assertion statements

**Quick-Start:**
http://weirddev.com/testme/

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way to write test for login activity

```
public class LoginActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity>(LoginActivity.class);

    public LoginActivity loginActivity;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        loginActivity = mActivityTestRule.getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin(){
        getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                EditText email = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.email);
                EditText pass = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.password);
                email.setText("email");
                pass.setText("pass");
                Button loginBtn = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.login);
                loginBtn.performClick();
                assertTrue(loginActivity.isCurUserLoggedIn());
            }
        });
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        loginActivity = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I should do to not commit `emal` and `password` to the source code repository, like github?

Comment: .gitignore will work :))